# Index of nth Occurrence of the string

Tags: c++, string

How do I find the index of nth occurrence of the given string in a line? I need this to take a substring from that index. Is that possible through any functions in c++?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is a `find_nth` template function in Boost: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost/algorithm/find_nth.html

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/find.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

int main() {

    string a = "The rain in Spain falls mainly on the plain";

    iterator_range<string::iterator> r = find_nth(a, "ain", 2);
    cout << std::distance(a.begin(), r.begin()) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This answer will give the last second occurrence, which is 25. May I know how could I retrieve the real 2nd index.

Comment: @huahsin68: the index is zero-based as it's stated in find_nth documentation. Just use 1 to find the second occurence.

Answer (score 12):

For this you can use `std::string::find` and keep track of the returned position. While doing this you can check to see if the desired string is not found as well and return a -1.

```
#include <string>

int nthOccurrence(const std::string& str, const std::string& findMe, int nth)
{
    size_t  pos = 0;
    int     cnt = 0;

    while( cnt != nth )
    {
        pos+=1;
        pos = str.find(findMe, pos);
        if ( pos == std::string::npos )
            return -1;
        cnt++;
    }
    return pos;
}
```

Comment: Just a small correction, intialize pos with -1, as findme uses zero indexed pos.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the following function

```
#include <string.h>

int strpos(char *haystack, char *needle, int nth)
{
    char *res = haystack;
    for(int i = 1; i <= nth; i++)
    {
        res = strstr(res, needle);
        if (!res)
            return -1;
        else if(i != nth)
            res++;
    }
    return res - haystack;
}
```

Returns -1 if it can not find the nth occurrence.

Comment: line "res = res++;" seems to do nothing, would change it to just "res++;"

Comment: Or even better, `++res`

Answer (score 4):

A simple way of doing this using just std::string::find

```
size_t find_nth(const string& haystack, size_t pos, const string& needle, size_t nth) 
{
    size_t found_pos = haystack.find(needle, pos);
    if(0 == nth || string::npos == found_pos)  return found_pos;
    return find_nth(haystack, found_pos+1, needle, nth-1);
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't handle the case when it cannot find a particular occurrence very well. In my case, it returned a unreasonably large number. Love the simplicity of the code and the use of `size_t`.

Comment: I think the large number is `string::npos`. If no matches were found, the function should return `string::npos` just like `string::find` does.

Comment: That makes sense. Then I'll just handle the `string::npos` myself. Thanks for the code snippet!

Comment: We're trying to find the nth occurrence, I believe. This solution appears to return the nth+1 occurrence or string::npos...

Answer (score 1):

this template function should get the job done

```
template<typename Iter>
Iter nth_occurence(Iter first, Iter last,
                   Iter first_, Iter last_,
                   unsigned nth)
{
  Iter it = std::search(first, last, first_, last_);
  if (nth == 0) return it;
  if (it == last) return it;
  return nth_occurence(it + std::distance(first_, last_), last,
                       first_, last_, nth -1);
}
```

usage

```
int main()
{
  std::string a = "hello world world world end";
  std::string b = "world";
  auto it1 = nth_occurence(begin(a), end(a), begin(b), end(b), 0);
  auto it2 = nth_occurence(begin(a), end(a), begin(b), end(b), 1);
  auto it3 = nth_occurence(begin(a), end(a), begin(b), end(b), 2);
  auto it4 = nth_occurence(begin(a), end(a), begin(b), end(b), 3);

  std::cout << std::distance(begin(a), it1) << "\n";
  std::cout << std::distance(begin(a), it2) << "\n";
  std::cout << std::distance(begin(a), it3) << "\n";
  std::cout << std::boolalpha << (it4 == end(a)) << "\n";
}

=> 6, 12, 18, true
```

Comment: May I know which version of boost are you using?

Comment: @huahsin68 Where's the Boost here?

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to make use of the last parameter in `find_first_of`/`find_last_of` of `std::string`. One can do that in a following manner for the `last-nth` search:

```
auto find_last_nth(const std::string& haystack, const std::string& needle, size_t n = 1)
{
    assert(0 != n);

    auto found_last = haystack.length();
    while (true)
    {
        found_last = haystack.find_last_of(needle, found_last - 1);

        if (0 == --n || std::string::npos == found_last)
        {
            return found_last;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I really like rcs's answer which made clever use of pointers. I think that, outside of using the boost library, it is the cleanest way to achieve the result OP wants. However, I had trouble implementing it in certain codes which did not make use of pointers (I'm still a beginner myself), so here is an equivalent answer that does not use either pointers or the boost library.

```
int strpos(string haystack, char needle, int nth)
{// Will return position of n-th occurence of a char in a string.
        string read;    // A string that will contain the read part of the haystack
        for (int i=1 ; i<nth+1 ; ++i)
        {
                std::size_t found = haystack.find(needle);
                read += haystack.substr(0,found+1); // the read part of the haystack is stocked in the read string
                haystack.erase(0, found+1);     // remove the read part of the haystack up to the i-th needle
                if (i == nth)
                {
                        return read.size();
                }
        }
        return -1;
}
```